# Using a GROUP BY on multiple columns where records are grouped together if ANY of the columns return a match

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, merge, group-by

Let's say I have the following table:

```
Record_ID | Match_criteria_1 |  Match_criteria_2  | Match_criteria_3 | Dollars  

     1    |  A               |   V                |   F              |   10  
     2    |  A               |   W                |   G              |   20  
     3    |  B               |   W                |   H              |   30  
     4    |  B               |   X                |   I              |   40  
     5    |  C               |   Y                |   F              |   50  
     6    |  C               |   Z                |   J              |   60  
     7    |  D               |   L                |   P              |   70
```

If I try to use a pd.merge function on Match_criteria_1, Match_criteria_2, and Match_criteria_3, I would end up with 7 separate groups/partitions.

---

```
Record_ID | Match_criteria_1 |  Match_criteria_2  | Match_criteria_3 | Dollars     | Total_Dollars 

     1    |  A               |   V                |   F              |   10        | 10 
     2    |  A               |   W                |   G              |   20        | 20 
     3    |  B               |   W                |   H              |   30        | 30  
     4    |  B               |   X                |   I              |   40        | 40 
     5    |  C               |   Y                |   F              |   50        | 50
     6    |  C               |   Z                |   J              |   60        | 60
     7    |  D               |   L                |   P              |   70        | 70
```

As you can see, none of the records have the same Match_criteria_1, Match_criteria_2, and Match_criteria_3.

But what if I wanted to group records that have the same Match_criteria_1, Match_criteria_2 **OR** Match_criteria_3?

So using my example, Record 1 matches with Record 2 due to Match_criteria_1, Record 2 matches with Record 3 due to Match_criteria_2, Record 3 matches with Record 4 due to Match_criteria_1, Record 5 matches with Record 1 due to Match_Criteria_3, and Record 6 matches with Record 5 due to Match_criteria 1 (so sort of a transitive property thing going on). The desired result then is :

```
Record_ID | Match_criteria_1 |  Match_criteria_2  | Match_criteria_3 | Dollars     | Total_Dollars 

     1    |  A               |   V                |   F              |   10        | 210 
     2    |  A               |   W                |   G              |   20        | 210 
     3    |  B               |   W                |   H              |   30        | 210  
     4    |  B               |   X                |   I              |   40        | 210 
     5    |  C               |   Y                |   F              |   50        | 210
     6    |  C               |   Z                |   J              |   60        | 210
     7    |  D               |   L                |   P              |   70        | 70
```

where Total_dollars is the sum of every record that matches due to transitivity. So Records 1 and 6 may have no match criteria in common but they are still grouped together because they both match with Record 5. This leaves record 7 out since it doesn't match with any of the other records based on any of the three criteria.

Comment: Create a third columns expressing that, group by that

Comment: A third column expressing what? @ifly6